# Restore visibility of shell namespace extension

Tags: windows, shell-extensions

I have a namespace extension that I "accidentally" removed by right-clicking on it in Windows Explorer and then deleting it (Windows 7). The prompt I was given was that I could restore it in Control Panel, however I've searched/googled but I've yet to find where I can restore the extension. Help ? :)

Comment: What extension was it? What did it do?

Comment: It was the "Explorer Data Provider" example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd940360(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: 1) Can't you build the sample code provided? Even the Express Editions of VB/VC (whichever's needed here) should suffice. 2) If an Explorer shell extension is in use, normally you shouldn't even be allowed to delete the DLL until you un-register it. Don't know how you managed it, unless perhaps you used some Unlocker type utility. 3) If you simply deleted a DLL manually registered using regsvr32, I fail to see how Explorer would tell you that it can be restored via Control Panel. I've never seen this happen. Would be great if this can be reproduced so a screenshot of the dialog is available.

Comment: For 1)2)3) there are no issues. I know everything there is to know about registering/using extensions with windows explorer (ATL black belt ;) The problem is that if the DLL is registered with the SFGAO_CAN_DELETE flag set (in Attributes), you have the possibility to "Delete" the extension (right-click in explorer). If I do this, the DLL still has all data in the registry set (i.e it has nothing to do with deleting the DLL or unregistering it), and when I do this, I'm told (by explorer) that I can restore the extension in Control Panel. But where in CP eludes me. I'll try fix a screenshot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Under `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{your class id}\ShellFolder`

There is a setting

```
"Attributes"=dword:00100000
```

That appears to get set when you delete the icon representing your extension.

Removing the entire `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\CLSID\{your class id}\ShellFolder` hive worked for me.

Comment: Thank you @Dan. Still I wonder where the GUI for this in Control Panel is... :)

Answer (score 1):

See if this key is set:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\
 ... Explorer\FolderDescriptions\{GUID}\PropertyBag\ThisPCPolicy
```

If it's set to "Hide"... your extension stays hidden.

See more info here: https://www.askvg.com/tip-remove-6-extra-folders-from-windows-10-explorer-this-pc/